# estimates of a population

Tags: probability, statistics

An opinion poll in a certain city indicated that 69 people in a random sample of 120 said that they would vote for Mr. Jones, while in a second random sample of 160, 93 said that they would vote for Mr. Jones.  Find an unbiased estimate of the proportion of people in the city who will vote for Mr. Jones.

Comment: Hi, welcome to mathSE.  Do you have any ideas on what this problem means or how you might solve it?  What are you confused about?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** By "unbiased", they probably mean that *every person is counted equally in the estimate*.

The first random sample had $69/120 = 0.575$ in favor of Mr. Jones.  The second random sample had $93/160 = 0.58125$ in favor of Jones.  But *we can't just take the average of these two numbers*, because the second number included more people than the first number, so *we would not be representing all people equally*.

Instead, try pretending that there was only one poll, instead of two, and that that poll included all of the people in both of these random samples combined.

Comment: wat should i supozd to do?.. finding difference or otherwise?.. help me plz find an answer..

Comment: @Jobert If we combined the results of both polls into one, how many total people would have responded?  How many of them would be in favor of Mr. Jones?

Comment: @Goos..do u mean this way 0.575+0.58125=1.15625 or (69+93)/(120+160)=0.578571428571429 ?

Comment: @Jobert, the first way doesn't have an answer between 0 and 1, so it isn't correct.  But the second way is right!  Good work.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (yielding the same result as Goos) is using a weighted average, taking the number of people asked as the weight:
$$\bar{X}_\omega = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \omega_i X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n \omega_i}$$
Where in this case $n=1, \omega = (120, 160), X = (69,93)$

Comment: This isn't wrong, but it's decidedly unhelpful.

Comment: @Goos further elaboration would be equivalent to posting the solution right away. Weights can also be used in continuous context, whereas I see no generalisation for you method there...
I originally posted this as a comment to your answer, but it became a little long.

Comment: I'm not criticizing your solution on a mathematical level, I'm just saying that it doesn't help the OP in any way whatsoever.  It's like if someone asks you how to do 6 divided by 2 and you answer with an explanation from field theory.

Comment: @Goos Given the grammatical capabilities of the OP, you're probably right ;-)

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
{\cal F}\left(p\right)
&=
{\left(120 p - 69\right)^{2} + \left(160 p - 93\right)^{2} \over 2}
\\[3mm]
{\cal F}\,'\left(p\right)
&=
120\left(120 p - 69\right) + 160\left(160 p - 93\right)
\\[5mm]&\mbox{}
\end{align}

$$
{\cal F}\,'\left(p\right) = 0
\qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad 
p
=
{120\times 69 + 160\times 93\over 120^{2} + 160^{2}}
=
\color{#ff0000}{\large 0.579}
$$